# SP2013 TagProfile.aspx Related Tags display TagID not TagTerm

Tags: 2013, social-tag, keyword, tags

Clicking a tag from the tagcloud webpart takes user to a page called tagprofile.aspx which displays content that has been tagged with a particular tag.  Underneath the links, related tags should be displayed by term but they show as id.  Any ideas how to fix this?